# в таблице TODO изменить статус задания на выполненное, если только выполнены все дочерние задания

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring

Имеется основная таблица с списком задач. у каждого задания могут быть подзадачи, в свою очередь подзадачи могу иметь свои подзадачи (бесконечная вложенность).
заранее названия дочерних таблиц знать не могу, подзадачи добавляются по ходу работы.
по большому счету нужно узнать есть ли внешние ключи на конкретное задание.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Зачем тут 6 таблиц с одинаковыми полями?

Comment: подзадачи выношу в отдельную таблицу. не лучшее решение?

Comment: @tym32167 Видимо, в реальности таблиц больше (для бесконечной вложенности), но автор не знал, как показать в вопросе бесконечное число таблиц.

Comment: @Aleksanrd Это делается одной таблицей задач с полем `parent_id`.

Comment: @Igor то есть у меня все будет в одной таблице?  не до конца понимаю как child_id станет parent_id если у него появятся чайлды

Comment: Ну прямо таки напали на человека :) Александр, в одной таблице TODO добавьте столбец parent_id, который будет ссылаться на столбец todo_id этой-же таблице. И не child_id, а именно parent_id, так как у одной задачи может быть много подзадач. Далее, `select * from todo where parent_id = 42` - так можно получить все дочерние задачи. Соответственно, этим-же запросом можно проверять наличие подзадач перед удалением.

Comment: @Aleksanrd что есть "child_id"?

Comment: @Igor под "child_id" я имею ввиду подзадачу

Comment: @Aleksanrd `под "child_id" я имею ввиду подзадачу` - это бессмысленное заявление

Comment: @XelaNimed
спасибо за идею! попробую реализовать

Comment: @Igor и вам спасибо